# Undoing the alignment change of the Book of Vile Darkness

Tags: dnd-5e, alignment

So I'm the DM in a campaign (which I know gives me a lot of leeway) but I try to stick as close to the books as I can. One of the NPCs attuned to the Book of Vile Darkness, and failed the associated charisma save, so is now of neutral evil alignment.

One of the PCs is related to and will likely want to save this NPC without killing them. So my question is, are there any RAW ways for the party to change the alignment of an NPC?

In our campaign alignment has played a fairly large role, with some creatures fighting against their upbringing to become good when shown mercy and care by the party. However, I feel like a magical change of alignment can't simply be overcome by being nice to them. Since becoming evil, the NPC has become a lich and is attempting a ritual to steal the souls of various creatures to become even stronger. So the NPC is all in on being evil now, which is why I'm looking for a way for the party to undo the alignment change.

Comment: @GreySage I'd say there's a difference between changing alignment, and restoring alignment. For example, The Fates card can help with the latter, but not the former.

Comment: Related on [Are there official guidelines for a DM to change the alignment of a player's character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122046/are-there-official-guidelines-for-a-dm-to-change-the-alignment-of-a-players-cha) and [How do you make a character's alignment change in game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128237/how-do-you-make-a-characters-alignment-change-in-game)

Comment: I'm unsure if the above are duplicates because those are about PCs and not NPCs.

Comment: How big of a role does alignment play in your campaign? How has this NPC responded to their alignment change, and what sort of impact is that having/do you expect it to have on your story? And finally, is there a natural way I can work in the phrase "alignment realignment" in this comment (the answer turned out to be no).

Comment: @Upper_Case I updated the question to hopefully include the context you wanted on alignment in our campaign. I'm sorry you couldn't fit "alignment realignment" into your comment naturally

Comment: The fact that he's now a lich, and therefore literally needs to consume the souls of others in order to continue existence might be a bit of a concern.  Killing and resurrecting might or might not work.  At that point, he's not a dead person, he's a dead lich, and even resurrection doesn't work on the undead.  Also, it seems like various NPCs might disapprove of the karma houdini act.

Comment: I suppose True Polymorph might do the job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1st level Cleric/Paladin spell [*Ceremony*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ceremony) (XGtE, 151) has a bunch of listed effects, one of which is to restore the alignment of a creature that has had their alignment changed. Beware that this only works if the target creature is willing.

> You perform one of several religious ceremonies. When you cast the spell, choose one of the following ceremonies, the target of which must be within 10 feet of you throughout the casting.
>
> **Atonement**. You touch one willing creature whose alignment has changed, and you make a DC 20 Wisdom (Insight) check. On a success, you restore the target to its original alignment.

Players can also change their alignment by their actions, but you may rule that he cannot due to the fact that he is still attuned to the book.

Comment: You may want to further highlight the the creature must be willing considering that OP s creature isn't likely willing

Comment: ...but if you torture him *just enough*...

Answer (score 2):

### RAW

PHB p.122

> **Alignment in the Multiverse**
>
> For many thinking creatures, alignment is a moral choice. Humans, dwarves, elves, and other humanoid races can **choose** whether to follow the paths of good or evil, law or chaos. According to myth, the good-aligned gods who created these races gave them free will to choose their moral paths, knowing that good without free will is slavery.

DMG p.223

> Whenever a non-evil creature attunes to the Book ofVile Darkness, that creature must make a DC 17 Charisma saving throw. On a failed save, the creature's alignment changes to neutral evil.
>
> The Book of Vile Darkness remains with you only as long as you strive to work evil in the world. If you fail to perform at least one evil act within the span
> of 10 days, or **if you willingly perform a good act**, the book disappears. If you die while attuned to the book, an entity of great evil claims your soul. You can't be restored to life by any means while your soul remains imprisoned.

**Alignment remains a choice**. If the NPC chooses another path, their alignment will change.